# Is Latex the only choice, is there any (emerging) alternative?

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

I’m new to Latex, and I know I must learn Latex, the question: is Latex the only typesetting to write Math ? and it’s quite old, what is its future, is there any new (emerging/trending) typesettings are better and more advanced (like in IT, they have a lot of programming languages?)

Comment: I suspect you might mean the math mode TeX-based syntax (`$y = mx + \alpha$`) as much as LaTeX as a document preparation system. The former is used by a number of non-TeX tools, most obviously MathJaX.

Comment: Thank Joseph Wright. I may found helpful information from TeX-based syntax.